# Android XML using SAX Parser

Tags: android

```
<MenuByRole InstanceID="519" RoleID="614">
    <MainMenu Id="2298">Home</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="2431">My Results</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="2415">My Attendance</MainMenu>
</MenuByRole>
```

This is my XML file, I have retrieved all the ID values in this XML file. 
Here is the following code for that,

```
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu"))
        {
      id = attributes.getValue("Id");
      MainMenu = true;
    }
```

But I want to retrieve the specific Id value according to the name. For Example,
I want to retrieve the ID value **2298** with the help of **Home** name here

Comment: I have displayed the names like Home,My Results,My Attendace in Listview when I click on the List item I have to get its Id value. For example, When I clicked the Home List Item ,I have to get the 2298 as result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class MainMenu {
            private Long id;
            private String Name;

            public Long getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return Name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                Name = name;
            }

        }

    ArrayList<MainMenu> munuIDList;
        MainMenu oMainMenu;
        boolean isReadData;
        String sName;
        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MenuByRole")){
                munuIDList = new ArrayList<MainMenu>();
                isReadData = false;
            }
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu")){
                isReadData = true;
                oMainMenu = new MainMenu();
                oMainMenu.setId(attributes.getValue("Id"));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu"))
                oMainMenu.setName(sName);
            sName = null;
            isReadData = false;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            if(isReadData) {
            sName = new String(ch, start, length);
            }
    }

MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
ArrayLsit<MainMenu> lstMainMenu;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
               myListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
}

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lstMainMenu.get(arg2).getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I have displayed the names like Home,My Results,My Attendace in Listview when I click on the List item I have to get its Id value. For example, When I clicked the Home List Item ,I have to get the 2298 as result

Comment: Update me with logCat records

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.javatpoint.saxxmlparsing.MainActivity.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:106)

at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)

at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)

at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-05 14:40:53.280:

Comment: I have sent a mail to your email address please check it once is that I have sended to the right email address or not

Answer (score 1):

Below is full parsing Code.. You will get all ID from `listMenuId` and all name from `listMenuName`

```
String currentValue = "";
String currentTag = "";
        ArrayList<String> listMenuId;
        ArrayList<String> listMenuName;

        // Called when tag starts
        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            currentTag = localName;
            if(currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase("MenuByRole")){
                listMenuId = new ArrayList<String>();
                listMenuName = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            if(currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu")){
                listMenuId.add(attributes.getValue("Id"));
            }
        }

        // Called when tag closing
        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
        }

        // Called to get tag characters
        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            currentValue = currentValue + new String(ch, start, length);

            if(currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu"))
                listMenuId.add(currentValue);
            }
    }
```

Comment: You can use HashMap along with this solution... for key value pairs :)

Comment: Updated answer, check now

Comment: Here I am displaying the Home,My Results,My Attendance in a ListView when I click on the List item I want to retrieve its Id value